# Show two frames while one overlaps another

Tags: css, iframe, frame, frameset

I'm trying to show a small frame on the bottom right corner, like in the below picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSHT1.jpg

I'm currently using frameset, but I can switch to iframe if needed.

I know frames are bad, but the entire site is laid out like that.

How to make them overlap instead of them appearing side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<iframe id="frame1"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame3"></iframe>

#frame1{
    position: static;
}

#frame2{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#frame3{
    position: static;
}
```

Modify the top and left to your needs.

Comment: what if I have another iframe - frame3 - that should take the remaining vertical space after frame1? I am struggling with that bit now.

Comment: Edited answer to illustrate that.  You will have to add width and height's to each of the iframes to suit your needs as well.